# Three.js on Chrome Android : Error creating WebGL context

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webgl

I made a simple cube with Three.js for testing purpose. The thing is : when it runs on Chrome desktop, everything's fine, but on Chrome (37) on Android (4.1.2), the remote inspector shows :

```
Error creating WebGL context.
```

This error refers to this code : `new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`

I tried others demo (as http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/undulating-monkey/) I get the same error.

Is Three.js or simply WebGl not supported by Chrome on Android ?

*UPDATE*

I did another test on my android tablet (Android 4.1.2, Chrome 33), and it's working fine on it. Android Chrome 37 issue ? Or maybe my smartphone can't handle WebGL (hardware too weak) ?

Comment: I have the same error when running Chrome on Linux

Comment: Try with Chrome Canary or Firefox.